# Python 実行時のエラー TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex

Tags: python, matplotlib

Pythonのエラーについて質問です。
いろいろ調べてみたのですが以下のコードに対してのエラー解決ができません。
解決方法を教えていただけませんでしょうか？

**エラー**

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

**コード**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
g = sns.barplot(x="created_at", y="id", data=df_tweet.set_index("created_at").resample("H")["id"].count().reset_index())
labels = g.get_xticklabels()
g.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのご質問ですが、以下の 2 点を [edit] して追記いただけないでしょうか？　(1) 期待する挙動はなんですか？　(2) エラーを省略せずに全部コピー＆ペーストするとどうなりますか？（ユーザー名などは消していただいて大丈夫です）

Comment: 質問のソースだと、`df_tweet`が未定義です。おそらく`jupyter-notebook`とかPythonのインタープリタ環境あたりで、以前に作って再起動していない状態のため残っているデータでしょう。`df_tweet`を作成する部分も追加してみてください。

Comment: [【自然言語処理】PythonとTwitter APIでデータ分析](https://www.simpletraveler.jp/2020/04/02/python-twitter-scraping-data-analysis/)

Comment: 「いろいろ調べてみたのですが以下のコードに対してのエラー解決ができません。」とのことですが、重複を避けるために調査したことを教えてください。

Comment: マルチポスト先で解決済みのようです。 [pythonのエラーについて質問です。](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13239132168)

Comment: 反応遅くなりましてすみません。皆様アドバイス頂きありがとうございます。
こちらデータの入出力や加工の中で、時間情報が文字列型になっていた事が原因でした。修正を行い無事に動きました。
アドバイスのコメントありがとうございました！